# Is there a way to reduce Firebase Firestore auto generated Document ID?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document id autogenerated like Abxns67X8XasVCBXg5Sxk89oNa2nx and would like to convert it to something like gx7XNv ( a six digit Id).

Comment: What's your exact goal? Remember that a Firestore document ID must be unique across a given collection. So you can very well use 6 digits IDs as soon as they respect the previous statement.

Comment: But why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: I need it to save some ids in the custom claim in firebase auth. The limit length for claims is 1000bytes, this means i can only save about 50 ids (auto generated one)... But if i use 6 digit only, i can put more than a hundred

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans If you plan to add around 1000bytes of data in a Custom Claim, your approach is probably not the best one. As explained in the doc, having a lot of claims could cause performance issues because all authenticated requests always contain a Firebase ID token corresponding to the signed in user. If you explain what is your exact ultimate goal, we may guide you on a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, by using firebase firestre transaction by using my own ids for documents . Those ids where just Timestamp and to make sure there is not conflict with ids i used firestore runTransaction to make sure there is no other document which where using the same id i was about to insert. If there is , then i use a random 3 digit number to concatenate to that id. When done, i could reduce the id length from 16 to 7 as they were numbers